# How to read email using python from server and not the outlook application

Tags: python, email, automation, robotframework

```
import imaplib
import email
from email.header import decode_header
import getpass



# Rest of the code remains the same...

# Replace 'your_email@example.com' and 'your_password' with your Outlook email and password
username = '#'
password = '#'

# Connect to the Outlook server using IMAP
imap_server = 'imap-mail.outlook.com'
imap_port = 993

# Establish a secure SSL connection
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server, imap_port)

# Log in to your Outlook account
imap.login(username, password)

# Select the mailbox (e.g., 'inbox', 'sent', 'spam', etc.)
mailbox = 'inbox'
status, messages = imap.select(mailbox)
```

I tried this but got error :

> line 22, in 
> imap.login(username, password)
> File "C:\Users\ravich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 612, in login
> raise self.error(dat[-1])
> imaplib.error: b'LOGIN failed.'

I wanted to get the list of email that I have.

I am not the Full- admin of the email account so cannot change most of the account setting.

Comment: `# Rest of the code remains the same...` reeks of ChatGPT, anyway `b'LOGIN failed` means the login details might be wrong, are you 100% sure about them?

Comment: yes. I am sure of the credentials.